# Not sure which action to take while reviewing this First Post

Tags: support, review

I have very recently encountered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3700856/non-isolated-zero-on-boundary) question in the First Posts review queue. I did not know what action to take, as it looked more like a conceptual doubt than a homework question. While I was thinking about the most appropriate action, a comment had been posted, by a high-rep user which, I think, is a potential answer. This leads me to believe that the posted question is appropriately posted according to the guidelines.

I have skipped the review but I want to know what the proper course of action is, so I can apply that to similar questions in the future.

---

P.S: I have no knowledge about complex analysis. (I'm still in high school.)

**EDIT:** At the time of posting this question, the post had received a downvote. (Is this what I should have done?)

Comment: You should have done what you indeed did. If you don't know, skip.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, but I just can't keep skipping . I would need to know the procedure at some point of time , would I not?

Comment: That *is* the procedure. If you know what to do, edit/comment/vote/flag, do that. If you don't, skip. In due time, your knowledge of complex analysis will grow, and then you'd see that the asker failed to state that the desired function should be holomorphic, and that would make a useful comment.

Comment: @DanielFischer Cool, I'll take your word for it. Also is it okay if I flag the post now? :P

Comment: Thanks for asking here, @sai-kartik.  I wish more users would skip what they are unsure about, rather than merely guessing. Glad to have you aboard as a reviewer!

Comment: @amWhy Glad to help the community ! :)

Comment: You can also add a comment asking the OP to clarify the question add attempt or you can simply skip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did the [right thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/295232):

> If you're unsure about the post, *please* use the **Skip** button.

There's no shame in using Skip; somebody else will review the post and take the appropriate action.

The way this question is formulated ('Give an example', as opposed to e.g. 'Does ... exist?'), it is very likely to be a homework question (which isn't a problem) containing no research at all (which is). Downvoting and flagging/voting to close (as "A community-specific reason" → "Missing context or other details") are good options; providing an answer in the form of a comment is not.